# Automatically detect changes in GCS for BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, synchronization, google-cloud-storage

Now I have a BigQuery table whose data source is from some bucket at GCS(Google Cloud Storage).

The GCS is dynamic constantly with new files added in. So do we have any available mechanisms for BigQuery to automatically detect the changes in GCS and sync with the latest data?

Thanks!

Comment: you are looking for [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/), specifically for [Background Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background#cloud-storage-example)

Answer (score 0):

There is a very cool beta feature you can use to do that. Check out [BigQuery Cloud Storage Transfer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-storage-transfer). You can schedule transfers run backfill, and much more.

Read "limitations" to see if it can work for you.